# JSON не парсится в PHP

Tags: json, php, javascript

Здравствуйте.
Нужно сделать аутентификацию по клавиатурному почерку - банально по мере ввода запоминать время между символами.
На клиенте:

```
...
var obj = {
             //комбинация - между какими буквами
             combo: thisObject.prev_char + current_char,
             //длительность ввода
             time: current_time - thisObject.prev_time
};
//добавляем наш объект в массив  
thisObject.stats.push(obj); 
...
//отправляем
stats: Ext.JSON.encode(thisObj.stats)
```

Получаем вот такой json: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/FFCwtya5)
Cервер:

```
if(isset($_POST['stats']))
  $stats = json_decode($_POST['stats']);
else die('stats_no_send');
var_dump($stats);
```

Выводит NULL.
Всякие онлайн-валидации проходит и парсится, а у меня возвращается NULL.
Может есть идеи хоть куда копать, а то я даже не знаю с чего начать...

UPD:
Нашел функцию json_last_error(). Она говорит JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX.
Похоже проблема в том, что "внутри" добавляет кавычки экранируются. Фаербаг показывает, что отправляется без. А вывод даже echo $_POST['stats'] уже с экранированием. Откуда?

Посплю попробую)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась удалением экранирования:

```
$stats = json_decode(stripcslashes($_POST['stats']));
```

Но почему оно добавлялось для меня остается загадкой. Раньше такого не встречал.

Comment: Может включили экранирование на сервере у php?

Comment: @forum3, даже не знаю) намеренно точно нет) раньше php такого не требовал.